# how to check data in sqlite table using primary ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I create one application that use sqlite DB in it.
I have one problem and it is any time run my application add NSDictionary in my table sqlite. I want once check sqlite and if data exist in table sqlite not add else add it.

this my code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    sqlite3 * database;
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define DatabaseName @"data.sqlite"
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *idd = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"122",@"234",@"453", nil];
    NSArray *name = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"janatan",@"fred",@"john", nil];
    NSArray *age = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"23",@"35",@"12", nil];
    NSArray *sex = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"male",@"male",@"male", nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < [idd count]; i++)
    {
        NSString * a = [idd objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * b = [name objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * c = [age objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * d = [sex objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:a,@"id",b,@"name",c,@"age",d,@"sex", nil];
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into table1 (id,name,age,sex) values('%@','%@','%@','%@')",[dic objectForKey:@"id"],[dic objectForKey:@"name"],[dic objectForKey:@"age"],[dic objectForKey:@"sex"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",query);
        [self executeQuery:query];
    }
}
-(NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"PATH %@",[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DatabaseName]);
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DatabaseName];
}

/*==================================================================
 METHOD FOR INSERTING DATA IN DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/
-(void)executeQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    //NSLog(@"QUERY : %@",query);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"query Statement Not Compiled");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Data not Opened");
    }
}
@end
```

also I want when `NSDictionary` changed for example arrays is Dictionary increase value update sqlite complete.

please explain me .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this method :

```
/*==================================================================
    METHOD FOR CHECKING WHETHER RECORD EXISTS OR NOT IN DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/

-(BOOL)recordExistOrNot:(NSString *)query{
    BOOL recordExist=NO;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                recordExist=YES;
            }
            else
            {
                //////NSLog(@"%s,",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
    return recordExist;
}
```

It will return YES if record exists else not.
Ex :

```
          NSString *query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from yourtable where column_name = 'column_name'"];

        NSLog(@"query : %@",query);
        BOOL recordExist = [self recordExistOrNot:query];

        if (!recordExist) {
            // Insert your data
        }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: my friend I give error this line :    NSString *query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from yourtable where column_name = @"myColumn""];

Comment: Oops.. I made little mistake. Check now. Use like this :        NSString *query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from yourtable where column_name = 'column_name'"];

Comment: Did u check now , Is it working now ?

Comment: yes do it.thanks my friend I have one question and it is how I update my sqlite DB (for example if in my code in arrays (id,name,age,sex) additional one value how this new value add in sqlite or update my sqlite DB)

Comment: You need to update your table in database and then add one column in it . and then replace this updated database with the databse which is in your project. Then delete app from your simulator or device and then use updated database.

Comment: I so confused !!! how I update sqlite??? how to replace this update ??? I dont know about it. I have one sqlite file in Document folder application .

Comment: open your database you are using in app and then update your table for adding another row. and replace this database with old one. and the run query with this updated database.

Comment: thank you my friend I receive this data from json so any time possible this data changed. my friend how to understand how many row in sqlite table,please tell me last question??